# batch file to download and search for an update automaticly. it works. but its printing extra symbols and wont print the beginning

Tags: batch-file

```
@echo off
cls
Color 0A

if exist index.html del index.html
wget -q --show-progress http://cemu.info/
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion

for /f delims^=^ eol^= %%A in ('findstr /ri /c:"http://cemu.info/releases/" /c:"http://cemu.info/releases/" index.html') do (
  set "ln=%%A"
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  set "ln=!ln:*:=!"
  if /i "!ln:~0,5!" equ "http://cemu.info/releases/" (set "ln=!ln:~5!") else set "ln=!ln:* "http://cemu.info/releases/ =!"
  for /f %%B in ("!ln!") do if "%%B" neq "" echo "http:%%B" > cemu_ver.txt
  endlocal
)
if exist index.html del index.html
notepad.exe cemu_ver.txt
```

it works but instead of http://cemu.info/releases/cemu_1.8.1.zip

it prints "http://cemu.info/releases/cemu_1.8.1.zip""

(a single " at the beginning and a double "" at the end)

also http: is removed and it bothers me

is there anyway to fix that?

Comment: okay so it seems to be an issue with how the file handled the characters after. is there anyway to omit the character " from being read?

Comment: basically i need to search and delete all instances of " in cemu_ver.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why so conplicated, use the `"` as a delimiter and get `tokens=2`

```
@echo off
cls
Color 0A
if exist index.html del index.html
wget -q http://cemu.info/
for /f tokens^=2delims^=^" %%A in (
  'findstr /i /c:"http://cemu.info/releases/" /c:"http://cemu.info/releases/" index.html'
) Do > cemu_ver.txt Echo:"%%A"
```

Comment: also i tend to spaghetti code. thank you. (mine did work tho) but yours is shorter and simpler

Answer (score 0):

i found a workaround:

```
@echo off
cls
Color 0A

if exist index.html del index.html
.\bin\wget -q --show-progress http://cemu.info/
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion

for /f delims^=^ eol^= %%A in ('findstr /ri /c:"http://cemu.info/releases/" /c:"http://cemu.info/releases/" index.html') do (
  set "ln=%%A"
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  set "ln=!ln:*:=!"
  if /i "!ln:~0,5!" equ "http://cemu.info/releases/" (set "ln=!ln:~5!") else set "ln=!ln:* "http://cemu.info/releases/ =!"
  for /f %%B in ("!ln!") do if "%%B" neq "" echo http:%%B > cemu_ver.txt
  endlocal
)
if exist index.html call :add-quote
goto skip-quote

:add-quote
set /p cemu_ver=<cemu_ver.txt
echo "%cemu_ver% > cemu_ver.txt
del index.html
(goto) 2>NUL

:skip-quote
notepad.exe cemu_ver.txt
```